# Querying datetime in oracle

Tags: oracle, date, datetime

I have a date type column in a table, where I store date along with time.

I want to query it by `WHERE` clause
I did it this way:

```
select * 
from conference_hall_book 
where to_date(end_time,'dd/mon/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') <= to_date('26/oct/2013 15:00:00','dd/mon/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

But the result has 27/10/2013 8:00:00 AM also in end_time column.

Can any one help me finding the mistake?

Comment: Show the table definition please.

Comment: Isn't it a date already in your table?  Why are you converting the date to a date?  Why not `to_char()`?

Comment: end_time is in date type

Comment: Then just try: `WHERE end_time <= to_date('26/oct/2013 15:00:00','dd/mon/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')`

Comment: I converted to char, now working. And Other too is working. Thank you so much

Comment: If `end_time` is already a `date` then why are you converting it to a `date`

Comment: Please understand what you are doing, don't do it blindly.  The `to_char()` was a guess since I don't know what you're trying to accomplish and why you're doing it strangely.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem occurs because of

`to_date(end_time,'dd/mon/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')`

This is a wrong usage of the to_date function.  To_date converts a string to a date.
When Oracle sees this expression, it will automatically convert the end_time value to a string, using the configured date format of your database/session.  This format typically doesn't include the time part, so a date with the value of "27/10/2013 8:00:00 AM" will be converted to the string "27/10/2013" (if your database date format is dd/mm/yyyy).
Your to_date expression will then convert the string value "27/10/2013" back to a date.  The resulting date value will be "27/10/2013 00:00:00", so you will have lost the time portion of your original date.

The simple and correct solution is to drop the to_date(end_time) expression and just use end_time.  This will also ensure that if you have index on end_time, the query will be able to use that index.

```
select * 
from conference_hall_book 
where end_time <= to_date('26/oct/2013 15:00:00','dd/mon/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```